# Building OpenCV for Android from trunk

Tags: android, opencv

Following the tutorial found on http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk
I encountered problems with cmake.

when I run the command cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\android\android.toolchain.cmake .... from the build_android_arm folder I get a whole bunch of failures and then the configuration fails:

```
B:\Android\Workspace\OpenCV\platforms\build_android_arm>cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_
FILE=..\android\android.toolchain.cmake ..\..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - not found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - not found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - not found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - failed
-- Check size of unsigned int
-- Check size of unsigned int - failed
-- Check size of unsigned long
-- Check size of unsigned long - failed
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/TestBigEndia
n.cmake:51 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:439 (test_big_endian)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "B:/Android/Workspace/OpenCV/platforms/build_android_arm/CMakeFiles/CMa
keOutput.log".
See also "B:/Android/Workspace/OpenCV/platforms/build_android_arm/CMakeFiles/CMa
keError.log".
```

Error log mostly reports

```
Build FAILED.



"B:\Android\Workspace\OpenCV\platforms\build_android_arm\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2294351403.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-psabi' [B:\Android\Workspace\OpenCV\platforms\build_android_arm\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2294351403.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more googling, I found http://code.opencv.org/issues/3463

Which simply says to change

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\android\android.toolchain.cmake ..\..
```

to

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\android\android.toolchain.cmake ..\..
```

And it succesfully finishes after you've done that.

Comment: Thank you, this worked also for me, as I'm installing in an old Ubuntu (12.04)... (still some errors to solve, but solved 90% of my issues)