# opencv 3.0 beta for android

Tags: android, opencv

As there is no official package of the latest OpenCV 3.0 beta available for Android, does anyone know whether it is possible to build OpenCV for Android? Or do we have to wait till an official package is released?

I found this SO Thread how to build the old version for Android, but i doubt that it will work so easily for Android, and to be honest i'm not so familiar with CMAKE etc. to try it myself quickly.
[Building OpenCV for Android from trunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326306/building-opencv-for-android-from-trunk)

Comment: i would wait for the official release. a lot of functionality is still missing for the java wrappers

Comment: Actually i would use the c++ binding and the android NDK